# What does e:B, f:(B,A)=>B) : B

Tags: scala, recursion, higher-order-functions, fold, foldleft

I am confused about what this means.
I understand currying but I can't seem to read the code altogether.

```
def foldLeft [A,B](xs:List[A], e:B, f:(B,A)=>B): B
```

Comment: There is no curring in there. Anyways, what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand what e:b means or f:(B,A)=>B ): B, like if i were to write that whole code in english, I am confused how to.

Comment: `e: B` is just an argument called `e` of type `B`, that is just basic syntax, if you don't know that you should not be seeing that method. - Anyways, in English, `foldLeft` is a method that takes a list of any type, let's call it `A`, an initial value of any other type, let's call it `B`, and a function that takes a `B` and an `A` and return a `B`, and the whole thing returns a final `B` - conceptually, what `foldLeft` does is folding / combining all the elements in the list using the supplied function and initial value.

Comment: I am confused. What does this have to do with currying?

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "Explain this code to me" questions are off-topic, and what you can do to bring the question into a shape where it is acceptable for the site.

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple of advices.

By the way, there is no currying in

```
def foldLeft[A,B](xs: List[A], e: B, f: (B, A) => B): B
```

[Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) would be if you had `f: B => A => B` or `def foldLeft[A, B](xs: List[A])(e: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B` or `def foldLeft[A, B]: List[A] => B => ((B, A) => B) => B` etc. Now `foldLeft` is just a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (method), i.e. a function accepting another function (`f`).

- You can read wiki article about `foldRight`/`foldLeft`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Especially look at the pictures how we deconstruct a list and starting from what end we perform our calculations:

[image]

[image]

- You can think of `foldRight`/`foldLeft` as a just short way to define a [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) (instead of pattern matching a list and making recursive calls).

Let's consider an example. Let's have some recursion. For example let's have a wrapper class

```
case class Value[A](value: A)
```

And let's transform a list of `Value[A]` into a value wrapping a list of `A` i.e. `List[Value[A]]` into `Value[List[A]]`. For example we'd like to transform `List(Value(1), Value(2), Value(3))` into `Value(List(1, 2, 3))` (I actually needed such function [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860612/execute-splice-for-varargs-in-macro-method-in-scala-2-13)). Surely, we could do this with `.map` but let's pretend that we don't know `map` (it shouldn't be surprising that we can do mapping because `map` can be expressed via `foldRight`/`foldLeft`).

We can do this recursively in two ways (at least). Either simple recursion

```
def valuesToValue[A](values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] = values match {
  case Nil     => Value(Nil)
  case v :: vs => Value(v.value :: valuesToValue(vs).value)
}
```

or [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) with a helper function and accumulator

```
def valuesToValue[A](values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(values: List[Value[A]], acc: Value[List[A]]): Value[List[A]] = values match {
    case Nil     => Value(acc.value.reverse)
    case v :: vs => loop(vs, Value(v.value :: acc.value))
  }

  loop(values, Value(Nil))
}
```

Very simple. Just wrapping-unwrapping.

Both recursive implementations of `valuesToValue` can be (automatically) re-written with `foldRight`/`foldLeft`.
The former recursion can be re-written with `foldRight`. The latter recursion (tail one) can be re-written with `foldLeft`.

Let's re-write the 1st recursion with `foldRight`. The value from branch `case Nil => ...` becomes the 1st argument of `foldRight`. The value from branch `case v :: vs => ...` becomes the 2nd argument of `foldRight` if we replace the result of recursive call `valuesToValue(vs)` with a new variable `res`, so in the 2nd argument of `foldRight` we'll have a function of `v: Value[A]` and `res: Value[List[A]]`

```
def valuesToValue[A](values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] =
  values.foldRight( Value(Nil: List[A]) ){
    (v, res) => Value(v.value :: res.value)
  }
```

Let's re-write the 2nd recursion (tail one) with `foldLeft`.

First of all, let's recall that because of currying we can understand the helper `loop` as a single-parameter function into `Value[List[A]] => Value[List[A]]`

```
def loop(values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] => Value[List[A]] = values match {
  case Nil     => acc => Value(acc.value.reverse)
  case v :: vs => acc => loop(vs)(Value(v.value :: acc.value))
}
```

Now the value from branch `case Nil => ...` becomes the 1st argument of `foldLeft`. The value from branch `case v :: vs => ...` becomes the 2nd argument of `foldLeft` if we replace the result of recursive call `loop(vs)(_)` with a new variable `res` (a function)

```
def valuesToValue[A](values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] = {
  def loop(values: List[Value[A]]): Value[List[A]] => Value[List[A]] =
    values.foldRight[Value[List[A]] => Value[List[A]]](
                  acc => Value(acc.value.reverse)
    )(
      (v, res) => acc => res(Value(v.value :: acc.value))
    )

  loop(values)(Value(Nil))
}
```

So, roughly speaking, values from branches `case Nil => ...` and `case v :: vs => ...` become arguments of `foldRight`/`foldLeft` depending on whether we calculate with simple recursion or tail recursion with accumulator.

Comment: Wonderful explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Let's dive into this method signature:

```scala
foldLeft[A,B](xs: List[A], e: B, f: (B, A) => B): B
```

- `foldLeft` is a method with 3 parameters
- `A` and `B` are *type parameters*
- `xs` is 1st parameter of the method, of type `List[A]`
- `e` is 2nd parameter, of type `B`
- `f` is 3rd parameter, of type `(B, A) => B`

  - the type `(B, A) => B` represents a *function* taking two parameters of type `B` and `A` respectively, and returning a `B`
- finally, `B` is the return type of the method