# reduceLeft (or, foldLeft) vs reduceRight (or, foldRight) in scala

Tags: scala, fold, foldleft

I am learning scala from coursera. In the `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` description this comes along:

[image]

and then on the very next slide the teacher says this code pattern is abstracted out as `reduceLeft`

[image]

My questions:

1. I think the pattern in the first slide is `reduceRight` and not `reduceLeft`. Can you please help me understand where I am mistaken? For example: an addition operator on `[1,2,3]` would lead to `(1+sum(2,3))` from the first slide which, I think, is reduceRight. reduceLeft should be `(sum(1,2)+3)`
2. I am not able to implement the `reduceLeft` as `reduceRight` is implemented raw in the first slide using the `case` statements? Can you please guide me in the right direction on how to do it?

Comment: "*I think the pattern in the first slide is `reduceRight` and not `reduceLeft`.*" - yes, well-spotted! Of course most of the binary operators from simple examples (sum, product, concat etc) are [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) so it doesn't matter (and makes them more easy to confuse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Re 1.:**

Indeed, as already confirmed in the comments, the pattern in the first slide is `reduceRight`.

I think the point of the second slide is to say "that pattern of reducing a list can be abstracted out using a generic method from the standard library" (not "the pattern of the specific solution from the previous slides corresponds to `reduceLeft`").

Both `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` would be suitable to implement `sum`. However: when both `reduceLeft`/`reduceRight` (or `foldLeft`/`foldRight`) are suitable for a solution, in scala one usually prefers the `Left` variant (especially when working with `List`s) because its implementation is slightly more efficient on `List`s. That's most certainly the motivation for focusing on `reduceLeft` on the second slide.

**Re 2.:**

If you want to implement the `sum` from the first slide in a left-reducing way, you will need three cases:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match
  case Nil            => 0
  case x :: Nil       => ???
  case x :: y :: tail => ???
```

I leave it to you to fill out the `???`s.

Note that it will not be possible to implement this left-reducing `sum` in a tail-recursive manner (unless you introduce an additional helper function with a different signature).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think you have mistakenly written ```reduceLeft``` in your first sentence when you wanted to write ```reduceRight```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Let's recall definitions of `foldLeft` and `foldRight`

```
@tailrec
def foldLeft[A, B](init: A)(f: (A, B) => A)(bs: List[B]): A = bs match {
  case Nil      => init
  case b :: bs1 => foldLeft(f(init, b))(f)(bs1)
}

def foldRight[A, B](init: A)(f: (B, A) => A)(bs: List[B]): A = bs match {
  case Nil      => init
  case b :: bs1 => f(b, foldRight(init)(f)(bs1))
}
```

`foldLeft` is tail-recursive while `foldRight` corresponds to ordinary structural recursion over a list.

So tail-recursive definition of `sum` (with a helper function and accumulator)

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(xs1: List[Int], acc: Int): Int = xs1 match {
    case Nil     => acc
    case y :: ys => loop(ys, acc + y)
  }

  loop(xs, 0)
}
```

aka

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(xs1: List[Int]): Int => Int = xs1 match {
    case Nil     => acc => acc
    case y :: ys => acc => loop(ys)(acc + y)
  }

  loop(xs)(0)
}
```

can be expressed via `foldLeft`

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(xs1: List[Int], acc: Int): Int =
    foldLeft[Int => Int, Int](acc1 => acc1)(
      (tailRes, y) => acc1 => tailRes(acc1 + y)
    )(xs1)(acc)

  loop(xs, 0)
}
```

aka

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int =
  foldLeft[Int => Int, Int](identity)(
    (tailRes, y) => acc => tailRes(acc + y)
  )(xs)(0)
```

But ordinary structural-recursive definition of `sum`

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil     => 0
  case y :: ys => y + sum(ys)
}
```

can be expressed via `foldRight`

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = foldRight[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)(xs)
```

[What does e:B, f:(B,A)=>B) : B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915799/what-does-eb-fb-a-b-b)

Actually, in Scala standard library `foldLeft` and `foldRight` are defined via iteration rather than recursion

```
override def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these: LinearSeq[A] = coll
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = op(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}

final override def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these: List[A] = reverse
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = op(these.head, acc)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}
```

By the way, since `foldRight` can define arbitrary structural recursion over a list, `foldLeft` can be expressed via `foldRight` (the type `A => A` is chosen because `foldLeft` is recursively expressed via `foldLeft` for a different `init`, so we need being able to modify `init`)

```
def foldLeft[A, B](init: A)(f: (A, B) => A)(bs: List[B]): A =
  foldRight[A => A, B](init1 => init1)(
    (b, tailRes) => init1 => tailRes(f(init1, b))
  )(bs)(init)
```

Similarly, `foldRight` can be expressed via `foldLeft` (in by-default eager Scala but not in by-default lazy Haskell, because in Haskell `foldRight` works even for infinite lists, streams in Scala, but `foldLeft` works only for finite lists)

```
def foldRight[A, B](init: A)(f: (B, A) => A)(bs: List[B]): A =
  foldLeft[A => A, B](init1 => init1)(
    (tailRes, b) => init1 => tailRes(f(b, init1))
  )(bs)(init)
```